# why do i get an error in this json request?

Tags: json

this is my function:

```
   function transaction_create($wallet_id, $passphrase, $payment_address, $payment_amount, $metadata = array()) {
    
        $api_host       = "";
        $api_user       = "";
        $api_pass       = "";
        $api_url        = "/v2/";
        $api_endpoint   = "wallets/" . $wallet_id . "/transactions";
    
        // post body
        $transaction    = array(
            "passphrase"        => $passphrase,
            "payments"          => array(
                                    "address"   => $payment_address,
                                    "amount"    => array(
                                                    "quantity"  => $payment_amount,
                                                    "unit"      => "lovelace"
                                                    ),
                                    ),
            "metadata"          => $metadata,
            "time_to_live"      => array(
                                    "quantity" => 10,
                                    "unit" => "second"
                                )               
        );
    
    
        $curl = curl_init('https://' . $api_user . ":". $api_pass . "@". $api_host . $api_url . $api_endpoint);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($transaction));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        $api_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    
        // $api_response - available data from the API request
        return $api_response;
    
    }
```

this is the docs about the api:

https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/postTransaction

the part that is giving me the problem is formatting the "payments" array. the results of my function are:

> "{"code":"bad_request","message":"Error in $.payments: parsing
> NonEmpty failed, expected Array, but encountered Object"}"

then if i create a class and make the "payments" into a real object, i get the opposite error, it wants an array not an object... ??!!?? im confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc, Amount is an object, not an array - Also, so is Time to Live. PHP seems to have some gotcha's when it comes to JSON - my recommendation would be to try to capture the post as it is presented, and make sure arrays are [] and objects are {}.

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand what that means, that's probably why this isnt working for me haha

Comment: No worries, I may also be incorrect, but in JSON arrays are specified with [], where objects are specified with {}. So it's usually like ['Item1','item2'] as an array, or { 'key' : 'value' }. If you can find some way to see what it's sending to the API like write it to the console, it'd help you know if you're at least sending it the way it wants it.

Comment: I figured it out. it didn't understand that when it said the type was an "array" that it ment that it wanted an array of arrays. so i just added and extra array() to the $payments so it was an array of arrays and it liked that much better!

Comment: Awesome! If it helped don't forget to mark it answered :)